# 4 pin jack not detecting microphone on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, sound, 20.04, microphone, headphones

Please do not mark this as a duplicate as no posted solution has resolved this issue.

**Issue:** My machine (Asus GL502VM) is only able to detect an output device but no input device from my headset (Hyperx cloud mix), the port is a 4-pin jack to which the headset connects properly when running Windows 10 (sound + mic). The machine only has this one port and I have no usb adapters.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (also tested on 18.04 live CD)

**What I've tried for the past 8 hours that didn't work (reboot between each solution):**

- Change the hda adapter on `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, i.e. `options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-dmic`, also tried `alc255-asus` and `dell-headset-multi`
- Go on `pavucontrol`, admin and not, set the profile on the correct codec to "Analog Stereo Duplex", Go on Input devices and change the device on Port. I have "Internal Microphone (plugged in)" and "Microphone (unplugged)", they both pick up the machine's build in mic.
- Go on `hdajackretask`, select the correct codec, where only 3 pins are connected: "Internal mic" (12), "Internal speaker" (14), and "Headphone" (21). Check "Show unconnected pins", override pin 18 and select "Microphone", install boot override and reboot.
- Run `acpi_listen` to see the sound devices being plugged in:

```
    curli@clank:~$ acpi_listen
    jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
    jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
```

**please help**

Edit: Image of the headset: https://legitreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/cloud-mix-accessories.jpg

Comment: First off, I don't know your particular hardware.

Are you sure this model is supported in Linux/Ubuntu?  Have you tried one of the live CDs?  I suggest you try versions 20.04 and 18.04.  You could also try some other distribution.

Comment: I've tried 18.04 too. I'm not sure what you mean by supported, the cpu architecture is supported, asus machines aren't ubuntu ceritified though. I'm going to try other distros soon yes, if I don't manage to fix this.

Comment: Not every hardware is supported in Ubuntu.  "Supported" is a commonly used term.  If it's hard for you to understand what it implies just replace it in your mind with "hardware XYZ works fine in Ubuntu".  Some hardware that works fine in Windows does not work with Linux.  Of course, that might have been the issue in your case, but my research indicates that it is not.  I was wondering whether or not your headset is supported in Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: Thank you for adding an indication you've tried 18.04 as well.  I assume that was a live CD.  I suggest to add to your list of things you tried live CD XYZ and that still the microphone from your headset did not work when connected via cable.

Comment: Sure I get what supported usually means, I assumed you meant it as there being a way to verify if the hardware is officially supported by ubuntu, which I don't think there is (can't find it at least), I've seen some people successfully using other hyperx cloud headsets but not with my model (cloud mix), so it could be unsopported as in it could have issues with ubuntu by design, but I'm not sure how to verify that.

Comment: Yep, adding that to the list

Comment: Canonical offers certification for hardware manufacturers, but that's not what I meant.  See my "answer" where I was able to confirm via web research that your headset is supported.

Comment: I've had problem for years and finally gave in a brought a audio jack to usb converter, and it solved all my problems.

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] a picture of the aforementioned 4-pin jack into your post? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek added

Comment: @JohnSardinha: Have you been able to contact  [K1ndElk](https://www.reddit.com/user/K1ndElk/)?

Comment: @JohnSardinha by 4 pin connector do you mean the USB connector bottom center of the image you posted? If so, please [edit] the output of `lsusb` into your post with the headphones connected to the system. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek: My guess would be that he is referring to the [4-pin 3,5mm audio connector](https://media.cablematic.com/__sized__/images_1000/tw06500-01-thumbnail-1080x1080-70.jpg).  But then I'm not JohnSardinha.

Comment: @MAV I'm trying to avoid guessing for obvious reasons

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm using the 4-pin connector, in the center it's a mini-usb (to charge it), and on the right a splitter, but my machine doesn't have seperate mic and sound inputs

Comment: @JohnSardinha My apologies but I'm still not clear on what you mean. Perhaps [edit] the output of `lsusb` into your post with them connected and disconnected? Are you attempting to connect is via the analog connectors and the usb connector simultaneously? Doesn't sound prudent to me. Sorry I don't have your hardware so I can't test.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, I don't know your particular hardware and of course any number of things could be wrong, including but not limited to hardware problems, mechanical issues, configuration problems, bugs, driver issues, etc.  Very hard to troubleshoot from afar.

Again, just a shot in the dark, K1ndElk on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperX/comments/a7hxua/hyperx_cloud_mix_microphone_doesnt_work_through/) said that for them it was simple a connection issue.  That one had to push one of the connections pretty hard.  The good news is that this confirms it should work on Linux, something that apparently [the manufacturer does not test and thus does not guarantee to be the case for their hardware](https://www.reddit.com/r/HyperX/comments/7w5zqj/hyperx_cloud_flight_on_linux/).  They are active in Reddit and supporting even their Linux customers, though.  Have you talked to them?  It's probably a good idea to send a message to [K1ndElk](https://www.reddit.com/user/K1ndElk/) as well to see if they can help you figure out where the issue is.

I assume your headset works fine on Bluetooth even in Ubuntu, right?